# Two Engines Powering One Prop via a Shared Pulley

Tags: paraglider

This question is specifically in reference to Paramotoring. I've seen several videos about paramotors powered by the RC Engine DLE 170, and in all of them it struggled to spin the prop at it's peak 7500 rpm, instead being limited by power to about 5-6k rpm. So my idea was putting two DLE 170s in sequence and combining the power via  shared pulley, at a rate of 1:1.3 or 1:1.25 to put both motors in their powerband and get the full potential out of them. Would this even work? I haven't seen evidence of anyone else running this setup, which usually means there's something wrong with the idea. In theory it would weigh similar to a Moster 185 and have a slightly higher output, assuming there isn't an excessive efficiency loss in the design.

Comment: "assuming there isn't an excessive efficiency loss in the design." Your assumption will rapidly proven wrong ...